# no data sent on post form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've got a simple form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new-tag-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputTagName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTagName">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And a button

```
<button id="create-tag" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
```

I want to post form (send `json` data) when I click on that button. To do that I added a function

```
$('#create-tag').click(function() {
    $.post(
            "/tags-rest/tag",
            $('#new-tag-form').serialize(),
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
    );
});
```

But when I click on that button - it sends request without any data from the form. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only form controls that have a `name` attribute ever get sent to server using browser default submit process or included in `serialize()`

The `name` is used for the key in key/value pairs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTagName" name="tagname">
```